# android : option menu doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, menu

i am trying to make an stylish option menu which with text and icons close to this:

[image]

but i am still getting this:

http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/3007/resultax.th.png

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionb_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

The actionb_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
         android:id="@+id/item1"
         android:title="ajouter"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_plus" >

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item2" 
        android:title="rechercher" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_loupe">

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item3" 
        android:title="editer" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_crayon">

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item4" 
        android:title="supprimer" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_poubelle" >

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item5" 
        android:title="à propos"  
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_poubelle">

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item6" 
        android:title="Quitter"  
        android:icon="@drawable/call">        
    </item>

</menu>
```

any one can help please? any ideas hints??

Comment: It is possible this is related to the version you are compiling to (I assume 14+?)  What you're getting is the new preferred way, wherein Android wants you to have an ActionBar for your icons and the overflow menu to appear as such.  It looks as if you are essentially trying to duplicate the actionbar.  Have you looked into using ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: @Navarr no i didn't look into using ActionBarSherlock, i will do it right away.

Comment: @Navarr if there's a solution with an overflow menu it will certainly be helpful to hear it. Thank for your answers.

Comment: I gave you an answer both for what I recommend you do, and how to do what you said you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this isn't an actual answer to your specific question, you might try going about this a different way.

What you get is the new type of Options Menu for Android ICS devices.  What you say you want is the old style Options Menu from Pre-Honeycomb devices.  Android is trying to phase this out however, along with the menu button.

Instead, It is recommended you use an ActionBar.  [The design details of the Action Bar are covered heavily on the Android Design website.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

This would move your buttons up into the Top Bar, as it looks like you're already trying to do from  your screenshot.  You could either go through the difficult steps (that I don't know) to use ActionBar for newer devices and do something else for older devices - or you could use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to use the ActionBar for all Android devices.  [ActionBarSherlock's website has more details and instructions for setting it up](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), and their github has code and samples of it in use.

If instead what you want to do is truly get the old fashioned menu, you can change your TargetBuild to a lesser Android version.  This is generally done in the properties for your project.

Comment: i changed the targeted ICS, it worked. i will try to implement ActionBarScherlock later though. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is how settings menu appears on ICS Android 4.0.

Check your target platform  and change it to 2.3.3.

Comment: can you tell me more about it please.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `return true` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` implementation to `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`. The method should chain upwards.

Comment: still getting the same result